# change collection view cell background colour dynamically on button action not working

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I try to change the background colour of specific cell on button action. Color of cell is changing but but I scrolling this collection view the color of cell misplace from there original position [image: first time when I click on button to change the color]

when I scrolling this collection view which contain question number, color position in this control misplaced like in this image[image: color position change after scrolling here and there]

How I can handle this problem that collection view cell color never change their position automatically.

This is my code on button click to change the color :

```
let indexs = IndexPath(row: currentQuestion, section: 0)
let celi = questionNumberCollection.cellForItem(at: indexs)
celi?.backgroundColor = .blue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problems is**

You are changing the background color of the cell but you're not maintaining the state of the cell anywhere in your model which is important in the case where the cell is reused while scrolling.

**Solution:**

A simple and standard solution might be maintaining a state variable in a model or as a separate array, and change the background color in the *cellforRowatIndexPath* method.

**Example:**

```
struct Question {

    var desc:String
    var mark:Int
    var status:AnsweringStatus
}

enum AnsweringStatus {
    case notAttented,correct,inCorrect
}

class ViewController:UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var dataSource:[Question]!


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ShowCell", for: indexPath) as! ShowCell
        switch dataSource[indexPath.row].status {

        case .notAttented:
            cell.backgroundColor = .gray
        case .correct:
             cell.backgroundColor = .red
        case .inCorrect:
             cell.backgroundColor = .green
        }
        return cell
    }

}
```

Have showcased only the parts necessary to solve the issue. So on click of the button just changing the state in the respective model object using the index path and reloading the collection view will do the job.

Provide more insights about the issue, if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem was that CollectionViews and TableView reuse the cells.

In your CollectionViewCell class use this method to reset the reused Cell to default values or Colors.

```
@IBAction func onButtonTappet(sender: UIButton) {

   let indexs = IndexPath(row: currentQuestion, section: 0)
   let cell = questionNumberCollection.cellForItem(at: indexs) as? MyCell
   cell?.onButtonTapped = true
}

class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var onButtonTapped: Bool = false {
        didSet { checkBackgroundColor() }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        checkBackgroundColor()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        checkBackgroundColor()
    }

    private func checkBackgroundColor() {
        self.backgroundColor = onButtonTapped ? myTappedColor : myDefaultColor
    }
}
```

Comment: it will change all cell background with default color

Comment: this is not a solution.

Comment: You should set a property in your CollectionViewCell and if button was pressed set it to true, in prepareForReuse check if flag was true add your Color else default color

Comment: which property you are talking about?

Comment: Add a custom property, create one.

Comment: there are four different color and three button are which setting these color on cell.